# Resize images in grid without going out of view

Tags: html, css

I want to have images in a grid that resizes to fit based on the width and height of the window. It should go up to the maximum size (which is the the smallest dimension, either window height or width) while retaining the aspect ratio. Basically so that the images are as large as they can be without going out of view.

I have tried using combinations of min and max height in CSS with little luck. Here is the code I am using right now:

http://jsfiddle.net/5JCBD/

CSS:

```
    body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #tileContainer {
        width:95%;
        height:90%;
        margin:auto;
        background-color:#0F3;

        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        position:absolute;
    }

    .row {
        display:inline-block;
        width:100%;
    }

    .tileContainer {
        height:16%;
        width:20%;
        float:left;
    }

    .tileImage {
        width:100%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="tileContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
        <div class="tileContainer">
            <img class="tileImage" src="http://placehold.it/500x500/" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, then this solution may work for you.

Update your CSS to this: **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/5JCBD/1/)**

```
 .tileContainer {
   height:16%;
   width:20%;
   min-width:75px; //set this to the smallest your want your images displayed at. 
   float:left;
 }
```

Note, by setting a `min-width` once the window is sized down enough your images will wrap down to the next line.

Comment: I was having a hard time figuring out the words to explain my question. Basically, the images need to get smaller as the view gets smaller so they fit.

Comment: @block14, I was already seeing that behavior in your example fiddle. What issue are you currently having on your side?

Comment: My issue is when the height of the view gets smaller the images go out of view (go wide and short).

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it well, if you'd like, I can make some images to explain this.

Comment: So you want the images to be responsive to height and not just width? This isn't possible if you're wanting to preserve the image's aspect ratio. Otherwise you could probably do this, but it would stretch and squash the images (since the height would shrink but not the width).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I suppose I'll have to use jQuery or something. Thank you for your help!